# import com.kbzmai.skyfly.common Cannot determine what this is

Tags: jsf, dynamic, jar

I am following a solution presented in 
"How to generate dynamic columns in JSF Datatable?"
["How to generate dynamic columns in JSF Datatable?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632619/how-to-generate-dynamic-columns-in-jsf-datatable/39654723#39654723)

There is a reference in DynamicColumnBean to kbzmai.skyfly

Does anyone know what this is -- is it a jar file that needs to be downloaded and included in my lib ?

Comment: No they are 'model' classes from that user and custom mock classes ... Just create your own ones

Comment: Thank you! Kukeltje, always on point.