# Automatic generation of header p:columnGroup of p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

This question is about p:dataTable header manipulation.

I want to find a way to manipulate the header p:dataTable (primefaces) from java code directly, to make something like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="genericReport" value="#{mb.lazyData}" > 

        <!-- header -->
        <p:columnGroup type="header" binding="#{mb.header}" >
        </p:columnGroup>


        <!-- some data  -->
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="..." />
        </p:column> 

</p:dataTable>
```

Where #{mb.header}" is a java code read from a XML, manipulated by a tree through XPath.

I want to do this because I have a lot of reports  with a complex header; I mean, diferents levels, diferents conbination of cells.

UPDATE

The header could be with a lot of rows, not only one.  Here is an example of a a table.
[image]

This header has to be generated by an xml configuration. Here is the XML.

```
<header id="report">
        <column text="Granpa Pather">

                <column text="Pather 1">
                        <column text="Child 1">
                                <column text="Grand Child 1" />
                                <column text="Grand Child 2" />
                        </column>
                        <column text="Child 2" />
                        <column text="Child 3" />
                </column>

                <column text="Pather 2">
                        <column text="Child 4" />
                        <column text="Child 5" />
                </column>

                <column text="Pather 3">
                        <column text="Child 6" />
                        <column text="Child 7" />
                        <column text="Child 8" />
                </column>

        </column>
</encabezado
```

The colspan and rowspan is calculated by tree theory, it is  not  the problem.

I achievement to do this in a PDF y XLS (Itext and ApachePOI, respectly), using XPath and tree manipulation. My problem here is that HTML it is not so easy to manipulate. I think it could be to make using the API Primefaces.

Comment: It is totally unclear what you want to achieve... Sorry, can you elaborate/clarify?

Comment: Sure @Kukeltje. Recently i make and update. Thanks. I hope it is clear.

Comment: You can use `Component Binding`. Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39654723/8079165).

Comment: Thanks Tonkichi. I think that's what I was looking for, manipulation of p:dataTable from java code.